# HTTP 403 forbidden error when setting up virtual host for the first time in El Capitan 10.11

Tags: apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

I am setting up a site on my Mac OS El Capitan 10.11.4 (15E65) host machine for the first time, however I get a HTTP 403 forbidden error when accessing crmpicco.dev.

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/crmpicco/Sites/crmpicco.co.uk/"
    ServerName crmpicco.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       crmpicco.dev
```

This is my directory listing:

```
PiccosMacBook:Sites crmpicco$ pwd
/Users/crmpicco/Sites
PiccosMacBook:Sites crmpicco$ ls -l
total 71488
drwxr-xr-x  12 crmpicco  staff       408 18 May 19:06 crmpicco.co.uk
```

I tried changing the user that Apache is running, but that hasn't solved the issue.

```
<IfModule unixd_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
#User _www
#Group _www

User crmpicco
Group staff
</IfModule>
```

Am I missing something obvious? I have also tried this suggestion (Apache localhost 403 error with Yosemite)

Answer (score 1):

Check the Apache error log. If you find messages that say 'client denied by server configuration' then you do not have the corresponding `<Directory>` block allowing Apache to serve files from `/Users/crmpicco/Sites/crmpicco.co.uk/`.

If the error log mentions `(13) Permission denied`, then it is the OS stopping Apache serving files from that directory (not the Apache configuration itself) and you should look at the permissions of all directories in the path. Remember Apache needs to be able to traverse the whole path, not just the last component.

If the whole path is ok, then you probably have some form of security software running preventing Apache from serving the files.